# How to load a local gif with React Native?

Tags: gif, animated-gif, react-native

I'm trying to load a local gif for being used on React Native. My main problem is adding it to the Images Assets because Xcode doesn't let me add it to the asset. I've read on GitHub that there's no problem showing an animated gif using React Native but I only have found examples with external images and I need to be loaded locally as it is an important asset for my app.

`<Image source={require('image!loading')} />`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode7-beta you can add .gif files - no problem with that. In Xcode6  you indeed can't but I have found that you can simply change extension of the  image to .png, add it to assets and wen you use the name (no extension) it will show the gif (including animated gif). It's an interesting workaround :)

Comment: Hi Jarek, thanks for your reply. I'm using Xcode7-beta (I forgot to mention that) and unfortunately I'm not able to add the gif file anyway. I'm trying to drag the file to xCode and nothing happens. If I try that with a jpg file it works as expected. I'll try to change the extension...